# how to make my changed data appear after using viewmodel

Tags: java, android

source code: [popularMovie](https://github.com/mayadaaa/popularMovie.git)

I'm using viewmodel to retrieve the data and load all movies when I click on favorites menu item ,but it dosen't work and doesn't appear when I click

viewmodel rooming and DAO

```java
private void setupViewModel() {

            MainViewModel viewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
            viewModel.getFavS().observe(this, new Observer<List<FavouritMovie>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<FavouritMovie> Favourites) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "retrieve data from LiveDtata in viewModel");

                for (int i=0;i<Favourites.size();i++) {
                    FavouritMovie mov = new FavouritMovie(Favourites.get(i).getId(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getTitle(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getReleaseDate(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getVoteAverage(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getPopularity(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getOverview(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getPosterPath(),
                            Favourites.get(i).getBackdropPath()
                    );

                    Favourites.add(mov);
                }
                adapter.setTasks(Favourites);

                }
            });
    //this method i call when i click on favorites menu item
```

I expect to load all stores movies in database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change your data inside you `observe` callback function.
You have to do that outside using `insert`, `update` or `delete` ViewModel functions.
The `onChanged` function is called AFTER using these methods, and especially to update your adapter list.

```
        MainViewModel viewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getFavS().observe(this, new Observer<List<FavouritMovie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<FavouritMovie> Favourites) {
                adapter.setTasks(Favourites);
            }
        });
```

And to insert new data use `viewModel.insert`.

Comment: i'm using it to load all movies not insert or delete so what s the problem

Comment: Because you are doing `Favourites.add(mov);` inside `onChanged`, I thought you want to add new movies. Are you sure there are movies in your database?